# archiving logback files which has the process name

Tags: logging, logback

I have a logback appender like the one below

```
<appender name="file-appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <Prudent>true</Prudent>
        <file>/logs/${processName}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/logs/${processName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>7</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

I have a webapp which starts multiple Java processes. The processes start and die off generating separate log files. The generated files never get archived or removed as the FileNamePattern keeps changing.

For example lets say that the webapp process name is webapp and the generated processes have names process1, process2 ,process3 etc.. This generates the below set of log files.

```
webapp.log
process1.log
process2.log
process3.log
....
processn.log
```

Now the appender archives/removes webapp.log correctly, but cannot  remove the `process*.log` logs as the process which were writing to that log file has already died off and the webapp which is still alive uses a different log file name.

The webapp keeps generating new process very often. Is there a way to get the logs removed after 7 days? May be a custom rollingpolicy?

Comment: To understand this, is the problem this - How do I gzip the logs if the jvm process that generated it dies?

Comment: yes, it is - How do I gzip/remove logs if  the jvm process that generated it dies off and another process which uses logback is still around.

Comment: Logback cannot help here since the jvm died. Probably the webapp process can do the gzip manually.